# how to bind data with checkbox angular 2?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5

JSON

```
[ {
  "code" : "TEST",
  "projectId" : "PROJECT",
  "name" : "TEST",
  "description" : "test",
  "level1" : "1 ",
  "level2" : "2 ",
  "level3" : "3",
  "level4" : "4",
  "level5" : "5",
  "active" : false
}, {
  "code" : "test",
  "projectId" : "PROJECT",
  "name" : "Test",
  "description" : "test 11",
  "level1" : "1 ",
  "level2" : "2 ",
  "level3" : "3",
  "level4" : "4",
  "level5" : "5",
  "active" : true
}, {
  "code" : "asdasd2122",
  "projectId" : "PROJECT",
  "name" : "TEST12",
  "description" : "ashdasdhl",
  "level1" : "1 ",
  "level2" : "2 ",
  "level3" : "3",
  "level4" : "4",
  "level5" : "5",
  "active" : false
}, {
  "code" : "test1a",
  "projectId" : "PROJECT",
  "name" : "TEST122",
  "description" : "a,sndkajlskdjlkajd",
  "level1" : "1 ",
  "level2" : "2 ",
  "level3" : "3",
  "level4" : "4",
  "level5" : "5",
  "active" : true
}, {
  "code" : "dasdasd",
  "projectId" : "PROJECT",
  "name" : "test123123",
  "description" : "asdasdasd",
  "level1" : "1 ",
  "level2" : "2 ",
  "level3" : "3",
  "level4" : "4",
  "level5" : "5",
  "active" : true
}, 
 {
  "code" : "asdasdTES",
  "projectId" : "PROJECT",
  "name" : "TEST123",
  "description" : "asdasdasd",
  "level1" : "1 ",
  "level2" : "2 ",
  "level3" : "3",
  "level4" : "4",
  "level5" : "5",
  "active" : true
} ]
```

HTML

```
            <mat-table [dataSource]="offersColumnRowData" matSort matSortActive="NAME">

          <ng-container matColumnDef="SELECT">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> SELECT </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <mat-checkbox>
              </mat-checkbox>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="NAME">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> NAME </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.name }} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="CODE">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CODE </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{ element.code }} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="DESCRIPTION">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> DESCRIPTION </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{ element.description}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="CREATEDATE">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CREATEDATE </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="UNAME">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> UNAME </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <ng-container matColumnDef="ISACTIVE">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ISACTIVE </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
              <mat-checkbox type="checkbox">
              </mat-checkbox>
            </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="offersColumns"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: offersColumns;" (mouseover)="row.hovered = true" (mouseout)="row.hovered = false"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
```

I'm trying to bind values into checkbox! the values in form of boolean (TRUE|FALSE)

I have tried to bind the with check box but its not working

Explaination: goto to my stackblitz -> if i select any checkbox from SELECT column the code column should be selected(i just want to print select column row CODE in console log)

2) how to bind Boolean values into checkbox column that column name is ISACTIVE if active is false check box is not selected if active is true -> checkbox is selected!

Here it is my stackblits link it would be easy for you!

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbf9kz-a2s4zc?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Comment: `<mat-checkbox type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="element.active">`

Comment: thank you @Ric but if i select check box from SELECT column i want to print selected row CODE column data could you please help me that

Comment: See my answer below. It will allow you to get the code from the selected checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how complex you're going to go with this, you could either take a forms approach (recommended), or you can add a simple change handler to your checkbox.

*COMPONENT*

```
selectedCodes: string[] = [];

receiveCheckboxChange(code: string, value: MatCheckboxChange) {
   console.log(code, value.checked);
   this.updateCodes(code, value.checked);
}

updateCodes(code: string, selected: boolean) {
   const inArrayIndex: number = this.selectedCodes.indexOf(code);
   if (selected && inArrayIndex === -1) {
      this.selectedCodes.push(code);
   } else if (inArrayIndex !== -1) {
      this.selectedCodes.splice(inArrayIndex, 1);
   }
}

isSelected(code: string) {
    return this.selectedCodes.indexOf(code) !== -1;
}
```

*TEMPLATE*

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="ISACTIVE">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ISACTIVE </mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <mat-checkbox type="checkbox" (change)="receiveCheckboxChange(element.code, $event)" [checked]="isSelected(element.code)">
            </mat-checkbox>
        </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

The key part here being `(change)="receiveCheckboxChange(element.code, $event)"` - You can supply whatever info you want from the `element`, or, indeed, the entire `element` object itself to your function. Then it's up to you to do whatever you want from there.

You will then have an array of selected codes in the variable `selectedCodes`. What you do with them from there, is up to you.

Blitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbf9kz-sgtrtv

Comment: Yes you are right! when i select check box from CHECKBOX column the code column value i want to print but i actually i want to pass this CODE value to the API do you get my Qn? so could you tell me how to store this code value in to any variable?

Comment: You can do whatever you like with the `code` value inside `receiveCheckboxChange` - you can store it as a variable, add it to an array, or directly call an API. It's up to you. :)

Comment: how to store that code value in to variable? could you please tell me!

Comment: just one mistake you should show selected CODE on the basis of SELECT column check box thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="SELECT">
                <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> SELECT </mat-header-cell>
                <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
                  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="element.Isselected" (change)="change()">
                  </mat-checkbox>
                </mat-cell>
              </ng-container>
```

in ts file

```
change() {
    const result = this.offersColumnRowData.filter(x => x.Isselected == true);

console.log('result', result);
  }
```

Isselected property in json

```
"Isselected": false,
  "code" : "TEST",
  "projectId" : "PROJECT",
  "name" : "TEST",
  "description" : "test",
  "level1" : "1 ",
  "level2" : "2 ",
  "level3" : "3",
  "level4" : "4",
  "level5" : "5",
  "active" : false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [checked] and (change) to show if is element.active=true and to change the value of element.active. And use conditional operator to show (or not) the value of element.code

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="CODE">
  <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> CODE </mat-header-cell>
  <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
      {{ element.active?element.code:"" }} 
  </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
...
<ng-container matColumnDef="ISACTIVE">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ISACTIVE </mat-header-cell>
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
     <mat-checkbox type="checkbox" [checked]="element.active" 
                                   (change)="element.active=$event.checked">
     </mat-checkbox>
   </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

**Update**:Better using ngModel -not [checked] and (change)-

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="ISACTIVE">
    <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> ISACTIVE </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <mat-checkbox type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="element.active">
        </mat-checkbox>
    </mat-cell>
</ng-container>
```

Answer (score -1):

I updated your stackblitz, check : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbf9kz-qg9fvw?file=app%2Ftable-basic-example.ts

Bind data on checkbox html tag using `[checked]="element.active"`

Get active property value using `(change)="change(element)"`

Comment: thank you sir, but you solved only one query i want this also if i select check box from SELECT column i want to print selected row CODE column data could you please help me that

Comment: I updated the stackblitz project. Tell me if it's what you expected.

Comment: you are 90 % correct but i dont want whole row i just want CODE column value . when i select  checkbox from SELECT column then i want to store the code column value into any variable!

Comment: then you just need to do something like this.<name of the variable> = element.code into the print() method.